# load method stream

Tags: c#, winforms, load

I have an application which lets you edit employee details add new salaried employee and new hourly employee. I am trying to get data from a text file to show up on a list box in a windows form application. This is the code on my main form.

```
namespace HRApplication
{
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    // The file used to store employee details
    string employeesFile = "employees.txt";

    // The collection used to hold the employee data
    Employees employees;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        employees = new Employees();
        if (!employees.Load(employeesFile))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to load employees file");
        }
        else
        {
            PopulateListBox();
        }
    }

    private void PopulateListBox()
    {
        listBoxEmployees.Items.Clear();

        foreach (Employee employee in employees)
        {
            listBoxEmployees.Items.Add(employee.LastName + ", " + employee.FirstName);
        }
        listBoxEmployees.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

and I have me load method from another class here:

```
public bool Load(string employeesFile)
    {
        List<String> list = new List<String>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("employees.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                list.Add(line);
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }

            return true;
```

The data from the textfile will not show, how do I get it to show? Thank you

Comment: does your `Console.WriteLine` print anything?

Comment: I have data in my textfile?

Comment: Change Console.WriteLine with Debug.WriteLine. Then look into Output window if any data actually was read from the employees.txt file. Then tell us how you pass the local list variable, you are filling with strings in Load method, to PopulateListBox method, as it is not clear from what you wrote.